# Is this the correct way to use va_arg with pointer to function?

Tags: c, function-pointers, variadic-functions

In a function like this:

```
typedef double(*dfun)(double);

void tab(double x, int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, n);

    printf("%5.2lf  \t", x);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        dfun tmp = va_arg(args, dfun);

        printf("  %5.2lf  \t", tmp(x));
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```

Is it wrong if I pull the arguments like this:

```
    double(*tmp)(double) = va_arg(args, double(*)(double));
```

I came upon [this](http://c-faq.com/varargs/funcptr.html) article which suggest a different approach if it doesn't work:

> **Q:** I can't get va_arg to pull in an argument of type pointer-to-function.
>
> **A:** Try using a typedef for the function pointer type. 
>   The type-rewriting games which the va_arg macro typically plays are stymied by overly-complicated types such as pointer-to-function.

In my case it works in both versions (GCC 5.2.1), that's why I was wondering is one approach better that the other? Is there some potential error when I don't typedef the pointer to function first?

Comment: @KerrekSB It may be relevant, see my answer.

Comment: @2501: Thanks, nice find!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the a pointer without a typedef can indeed cause problems in some cases.

Standard explains that the `type` used in `va_arg` must be written in a way, where adding a suffix `*` will create a pointer to `type`:

> 7.16.1.1 The va_arg macro
>
> 2. The parameter *type* shall be a type
>      name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can
>      be obtained simply by postfixing a * to *type*.

Therefore to have compatible code, when using function pointers, you should use a typedef, because `*` cannot be added to a function pointer type as a suffix to create a pointer to that type, because the syntax isn't valid:

`(double)(*)(double)` =>  `(double)(*)(double)*`

but it can be added to a typedef:

`dfun` => `dfun*`

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is `typedef double fn(double);`, without the pointer, so that `fn*` is `double(*)(double)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB  The va_arg will not append a `*`, just the naming of *type* must be such, that if could be done. This rule is there because the macro is restricting the C syntax. Typedef can be either function or pointer to function. If you typedef as a function then the programmer must add the `*` manually.

Comment: Oh, right - the pointer is just used internally, of course. What you get out is the actual type that you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

The `va_arg(args, type)` is documented as (cf. ISO 9899:2011 §7.16.1.1 ¶2):

> The `va_arg` macro expands to an expression that has the specified type and the value of the next argument in the call. The parameter `ap` shall have been initialized by the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro (without an intervening invocation of the `va_end` macro for the same ap). Each invocation of the va_arg macro modifies ap so that the values of successive arguments are returned in turn. The parameter *type* shall be a type name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can
>   be obtained simply by postfixing a `*` to *type*. If there is no actual next argument, or if *type* is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

Thus, `va_arg(args, double(*)(double))` is not a valid invocation of `va_args` as `double(*)(double)*` is a syntax error and not the type of a pointer to `double(*)(double)` which would be `double(**)(double)`. Thus, a type definition is needed to be in compliance to the standard. The GNU C compiler is merciful in that it doesn't require this syntactical restriction, but your code may not compile with other compilers.

Comment: I accepted the answer above purely because it was posted sooner (about 3 min). They are both awesome.